# React URL changes but page doesn't change until refreshed

Tags: reactjs

It seems like this is the correct way but I'm still getting this bug. Everywhere I've searched has show to build it this way but it still doesn't cooperate.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './booking/Home';
import Login from './auth/Login';
import Register from './auth/Register';
import TopNav from './components/TopNav';

function App() {
  return (
  <Router>
    <TopNav />
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
      <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
)}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you tell your exact react-router-dom version from lock file. I would like to check syntax too.

Comment: I fixed it, idk why but I just had to re-run npm i react-router-dom

Comment: they changed defining route syntax more than once, that was what I had suspected.